# PHP trim returns string, trim on a double?

Tags: php, laravel-excel

I am using Laravel Excel to upload an excel file.

Using a foreach loop on the rows of data I am trimming whitespace and returning them as

```
$row[$k] = trim($v);
```

However, Excel stores dates as a number - which is of type double.

This caused many things to break because after the foreach loop, those doubles were cast as string.

What is the correct way to trim on a double?

Answer (score 0):

PHP trim takes a string and returns a string as well

```
$str = trim($v);
$row[$k] =  (float) $str; // Here if str is non numeric then it will return zero
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the output like so

```
$row[$k] = (float) trim($v);
```

Answer (score 0):

People have posted a solution to recast it like so:

```
$row[$k] = (float) trim($v);
```

However, not every cell is a double, we have `null`, `bool`, `int`, `array` etc...

I got around this like so:

```
if (is_string($v)) {
    $row[$k] = trim($v);
}
```

As Excel formats everything else correctly and only allows spaces in string fields this works.